# Why are my font-sizes so messed up when applying a margin to the body element in Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7.5?

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, web

I have a comparatively simple website in terms of HTML and CSS and it looks fine in Desktop browsers (IE9/Chrome). However when I view it in Internet Explorer in Windows Phone 7.5 it seems to make the text inside of unordered lists huge or tiny for some reason,

Here is code that produces weird results

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 250%;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 150%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 120%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>H1 header</h1>
  <h2>H2 header</h2>
  <h3>H3 header</h3>
  <p>Some paragraph text</p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Take a look at the size of the `li` text, it should be the size of the p tag but it is tiny. For a version of this file online see [this link here](http://brendan.sdf-eu.org/test/wp.html)

I have narrowed it down to the `margin` property on `body` and on a div, if either of these are set then the text proportions go crazy. Why does this happen? Is this a bug? I can work around this but it is far more convenient for me to set the margin on a container rather than all children individually

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems that internet Explorer mobile for Windows Phone 7 applies some kind of font-resizing to optimize the content, but this just ends up screwing up my site at least, see [this PDF 'Windows Explorer Mobile for Windows Phone 7](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/3/5/93565816-AD4E-4448-B49B-457D07ABB991/Windows%20Internet%20Explorer%20Mobile%20on%20Windows%20Phone%207.pdf) which explains briefly.

To stop this behaviour, include this bit of CSS

```
html {
   -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
}
```